# Configure Raspberry pi for my application to start on boot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, x-server, qt4

I have created an application through Python that has library dependencies on Qt4, pyqt4, pyqtgraph etc. This application is based on Raspberry Pi, I have developed and finished it on the platform.

I want to configure Raspberry Pi to only run that one single application. When I power the Raspberry Pi, it should not go to desktop but run the application (eventually only use necessary packages,library etc).

I have been looking around on different forums on how people do it, but it's not what I'm exactly looking for. There are also different solutions but it's just a bit confusing, that's why I'm here asking for advice/tips on how to implement that.

So far I've tried `sudo /etc/profile` and at the end of that file I call `python3 /home/pi/test.py` where I execute my application.

But I get `X cannot connect Server error` and Virtual Keyboard Florence is not really registering the button pressed.

Comment: use `/etc/local.rc` to start stuff on boot. see: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

Comment: @Bart Why not use a systemd service?

Comment: @RononDex, you can, personal preference here.

Comment: Why did you install an OS with GUI if you don't intend to use it? Switch to raspbian lite for example

Comment: @Bart I see, just personally I would use systemd services when possible, since then its not distro specific (any distro with systemd will work)

Comment: Hi guys, I'm not able to see my application when I start systemd, according to this website https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md, any idea?

Comment: I know the application is running because i get sudo systemctl status myservice.service but I cant find the application, GUI or anything..